# Finding a minimal subset of keys from a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, subset

For an exercise I have to determine a smallest subset of proteomes that contain all given proteins. The objects I can work with look like that:

A dictionary of lists which has the proteome ID as keys and a list of protein IDs of proteins that are contained in it. I also have an array of protein IDs. Multiple proteomes can have the same protein IDs.

**Question**: Find the smallest subset of proteomes containing all proteins declared in the array.

**Visualisation:**

Dictionary of lists

`{'UP000040088': ['A0A0T9TGA2', 'A0A0T9PBK6'],'UP000005347': ['I2WKK5', 'I2W7Q9', 'I2WH23', 'I2W8G3', 'I2W8S8', 'I2WCH8', 'I2WCJ2', 'I2WA21', 'I2WC26', 'I2WCG9', 'I2W9F2', 'I2WKG5', 'I2W4G7', 'I2WCD6', 'I2WG92', 'I2W6I6', 'I2W648', 'I2WE51', 'I2WKU2', 'I2WIG4', 'I2WED9', 'I2WEM0', 'I2WB05', 'I2W998', 'I2W7Q9', 'I2WA37', 'I2WD89', 'I2WEB4', 'I2W4G7', 'I2W4B1', 'I2WIM9', 'I2WI84', 'I2WIS6', 'I2WES7', 'I2WGL9', 'I2WIA8', 'I2W7H0', 'I2WDB3', 'I2WE60', 'I2WC93', 'I2WC36', 'I2WC86', 'I2WC82', 'I2W6J9', 'I2W428', 'I2WCH8', 'I2WCJ2', 'I2W9T1', 'I2W9B9', 'I2WC26', 'I2WCG9', 'I2WA28', 'I2WA21', 'I2W648', 'I2WE51', 'I2WKU2', 'I2WIG4', 'I2WEM0', 'I2WED9', 'I2W9F2'], 'UP000001592': ['A9IMD2', 'A9IU64', 'A9IWM9', 'A9IWP5', 'A9IZ28', 'A9IZ30', 'A9IZ48', 'A9IZ71', 'A9IZ73', 'A9IZ75']}`

Array

`['A9IWM9', 'A9IWP5','A0A0T9PBK6']`

The output in this example should be

`'UP000040088':['A0A0T9PBK6'],'UP000001592':['A9IWM9', 'A9IWP5']`

best regards

Comment: What have you already tried? Are you running into problems when coding? Asking for the working solution is not what SO is for

Comment: well, i tried a greedy method that iterates the array and searches for the first  key with the right value. However, this is obviously not going to give me the smaller subset rather than just a subset. I would like to get some ideas how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without using append and avoiding methods in for loops...

```
dct={'UP000040088': ['A0A0T9TGA2', 'A0A0T9PBK6'],'UP000005347': ['I2WKK5', 'I2W7Q9', 'I2WH23', 'I2W8G3', 'I2W8S8', 'I2WCH8', 'I2WCJ2', 'I2WA21', 'I2WC26', 'I2WCG9', 'I2W9F2', 'I2WKG5', 'I2W4G7', 'I2WCD6', 'I2WG92', 'I2W6I6', 'I2W648', 'I2WE51', 'I2WKU2', 'I2WIG4', 'I2WED9', 'I2WEM0', 'I2WB05', 'I2W998', 'I2W7Q9', 'I2WA37', 'I2WD89', 'I2WEB4', 'I2W4G7', 'I2W4B1', 'I2WIM9', 'I2WI84', 'I2WIS6', 'I2WES7', 'I2WGL9', 'I2WIA8', 'I2W7H0', 'I2WDB3', 'I2WE60', 'I2WC93', 'I2WC36', 'I2WC86', 'I2WC82', 'I2W6J9', 'I2W428', 'I2WCH8', 'I2WCJ2', 'I2W9T1', 'I2W9B9', 'I2WC26', 'I2WCG9', 'I2WA28', 'I2WA21', 'I2W648', 'I2WE51', 'I2WKU2', 'I2WIG4', 'I2WEM0', 'I2WED9', 'I2W9F2'], 'UP000001592': ['A9IMD2', 'A9IU64', 'A9IWM9', 'A9IWP5', 'A9IZ28', 'A9IZ30', 'A9IZ48', 'A9IZ71', 'A9IZ73', 'A9IZ75']}

a = ['A9IWM9', 'A9IWP5','A0A0T9PBK6']

match={k:[None for _ in a] for k in dct.keys()}

for k,lst in dct.items():
    n=0
    for ai in a:
        if ai in lst:
            match[k][n]=ai
        n+=1

print match # {'UP000040088': [None, None, 'A0A0T9PBK6'], 'UP000005347': [None, None, None], 'UP000001592': ['A9IWM9', 'A9IWP5', None]}

match={k:[vi for vi in v if not vi is None] for k,v in match.items()}

print match # {'UP000040088': ['A0A0T9PBK6'], 'UP000005347': [], 'UP000001592': ['A9IWM9', 'A9IWP5']}

match={k:v for k,v in match.items() if len(v)}

print match # {'UP000040088': ['A0A0T9PBK6'], 'UP000001592': ['A9IWM9', 'A9IWP5']}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. However, it won't work with multiple keys having a shared value. If for example `'A0A0T9PBK6'` occurs also in `'UP000001592'` I only want to return `'UP000001592'` instead of both.

Comment: so update Your input, Im thinking faster on input + output than on blablabla :P